# Getting program states from two different terminals and comparing them

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, programming

I want to run two different instances of a program in two different terminals. and check the variables inside the program if they match all the time or not.

What I really want to do here is, do observational Determinism in two different programs. I will be calling different functions in both the programs in both the terminal and their respective states.

How can I do so?

---

I will be running a program, that runs fuzzing campaign on a solidity contract(*these are the codes that govern the rule of an application on Ethereum Blockchain*).

This program `echidna` (https://github.com/crytic/echidna), run campaign only on one file of the contract.

I want to test the same file in 2 different terminals, with the same set of inputs provided to it.

So, here I want to compare the state transitions on both the campaigns. Som can I somehow, share their variable storage pool, and compare the states?

(*I will add the functionality to temporarily store the states*)

Comment: What will you be comparing? The program output? Then just redirect the output of each program to a different file and compare the files. I don't understand what you need here.

Comment: Let me make it a little detailed.

Comment: Isn't this more about programming and debugging than about Ubuntu ?

Comment: I thought its more of a terminal based, maybe sharing of the memory pool. Should I move it to stackoverflow?